# I want to make password protected android application

Tags: java, android, if-statement, passwords

I want to make password protected android app, but when in this simple program system is not matching two strings.

```
package com.pokmgr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainPM extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pm_layout);

        final EditText pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinET); 
        final String pass = pin.getText().toString();
        final String code = "ajaj";
        Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterBtn);
        enter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (pass.equals(code)) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainPM.this, Menu.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
                else {
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainPM.this, Menu2.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pm_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }*/
}
```

I have made Menu and Menu2 class, but every time Menu2 class is accessed. Even if I enter same pass that is "ajaj" [in this code to test]
i have defined both activities in manifest file.

Can't understand why pass.eqals(code) is not working

Comment: I would log the *pass*, log or debug which branch is taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `pass` to the contents of the `EditText` when the activity gets created. Instead you have to retrieve the contents of your `EditText` inside the `OnClickListener`.

Like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final String pass = pin.getText().toString();
    if (pass.equals(code)) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition, `pin` needs to be converted to a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: Not really as long it's declared final.

Answer (score 2):

Put `pin.getText().toString();` inside `onClick` of `button`. You are setting variable `pass` before the user actually entered something in `pinEt` *EditText*.